# How can I pass data to the activity in my app?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

If I press the share button that appears by long pressing the text, I want to send the text to other activities of my app. I move to another activity, but the text I want is not delivered. What is the problem?

This is the code of the activity that writes the text I want to deliver.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText editText;
Intent sendIntent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendIntent.putExtra("TEXT", editText.getText().toString());
            sendIntent.setType("text/*");
        }
    });
}
```

}
This is the intent-filter of my xml code.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <data android:mimeType = "text/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This is the part that receives the intent of the activity that I want to receive data from.

Intent receiveIntent = getIntent();
url = receiveIntent.getStringExtra("TEXT");

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
This is the intent-filter part of the xml code of the activity where I want to receive data.

```
<activity android:name=".MyWebBrowser"
    android:label="MyWebBrowser">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/*"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Where do you send the intent? You should use startActivity(sendIntent) somewhere to pass that intent to the activity you want?

Comment: @DanBaruch I want to send data through the share that appears when pressing the text again. So why shouldn't intent be used?

Comment: You should use intent. But you need to send the intent, just creating it won't do anything. You need to call startActivity(sendIntent)

Comment: @DanBaruch I also tried startActivity, but this only works the first time the app is launched. Is it possible to get the text in editText to be delivered when share is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example for you:

Instead of long press on `editText` I simply use a button, but nevertheless, the logic stays almost the same:

// MainActivity. From here we send the text from EditText to SecondActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.setAction("MyIntentAction");

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent.putExtra("TEXT", editText.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

// SecondActivity. Receives and displays text from MainActivity.

```
    public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    
            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            if(intent.getAction().equals("MyIntentAction")) {
                String str = intent.getStringExtra("TEXT");
                textView.setText(str);
            }
    
        }
    }
```

// For Long Click detection add the following code to MainActivity:

```
editText.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                intent.putExtra("TEXT", editText.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I have to make it in a situation where I do a long press, not a way to make a button. Is there any way for that?

Comment: @SeHoon edited my post with the code for long press.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SeHoon if the answer had helped you, please mark it as `accepted answer` using the checkmark on the left next to my answer. It's very appreciated.

Comment: Sorry. My question has not been resolved. It seems that I wrote it difficult. I wanted to send it to another activity by clicking the share button that appears when the text is highlighted. It wasn't just a long click.

Comment: @SeHoon Well, not exactly sure how to make only button appear on long press, but what you can do is make a layout appear with the necessary UI. Refer to this video from `Android Developers` youtube channel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OfEOYxWVRTM&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc91i2QT8qfrfKgLNlJiG1z7&index=7

Comment: I mean, if I press the letter for a long time, cut, copy, paste, share, etc. appear. I am hoping that when I click the share button at that time, the text I have selected will be transferred to another activity. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: @SeHoon it is possible. A video that I have sent you has information on how you can do that. Of course that will require a lot of new things that you need to learn, but that video (and all of those videos on navigation) can help get you started on right track

Comment: @SeHoon The only other way that I can think of right now is implementing an AlertDialog where you will pass the text and you will have all the buttons, but from my perspective, it's not a very good way of achieving this and I would definitely recommend the other, more wholesome solution to this problem.

Comment: I think so, but my professor doesn't. The professor is telling me to implement it via the share button in the highlighted text. Anyway, thank you for your help. I have to study the YouTube link you sent me and solve the task.

Comment: @SeHoon did your professor say that the button has to appear once you long press the edit text?

Comment: @Vittaliy The button is basically implemented in Android. If you go to any website and hold down the text for a long time, the text highlights and buttons appear above it. But I've never learned how to manipulate it, and no matter how much I searched for it, it didn't come out. Others besides me asked the professor about it, but the professor only said to implement it through that method.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using two activity has `LAUNCHER` with the `MAIN` in your manifest. Please use only one in your `manifest`.

To pass the data to another activity in your app, you can try to use `startActivity` and put your data in the intent data:

- On action to open the `MyWebBrowser`:

  ```
  val intent = Intent(context, MyWebBrowser::class.java)
  intent.putExtra("TEXT", yourtext)
  startActivity(intent)
  ```
- Get the Text in your `MyWebBrowser`:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       ...
       val TEXT = intent.getStringExtra("TEXT")
       textView.text = TEXT
    }
```

Comment: I already know about startActivity. What I want to know is how to control the "share button" when I long press text. If I do as you told me, the intent is already null before the text is highlighted, and I uploaded the intent-filter to use the implicit intent, not the explicit intent.

Comment: Sorry, But I do not clearly yet. Which intent is null? MainActivity or BrowserActivity?

Comment: BrowserActivity.

Comment: @SeHoon Try to get text in your intent from `onCreate` method and `onNewIntent`. I think maybe have something wrong here.